# After receiving update from CloudKit SwiftUI doesn't update child view, but does update if child view is inlined

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

This works as expected after receiving an update from CloudKit:

```
@Model
final class File {
    var name: String = "" // <- I edit the name on another device in the simple text editor, the editor code is ommited as it's not significant

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Query(sort: \File.name) private var files: [File]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ForEach(files) { file in
                NavigationLink(value: file) {
                    Text(file.name) // <- The text updates successfully after CloudKit sync
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the same app, but with extracted sub-views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query(sort: \File.name) private var files: [File]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            FilesView(files: files) // <- Just wrapped the code into a separate view
        }
    }
}

struct FilesView: View {
    var files: [File]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(files) { file in
            NavigationLink(value: file) {
                FileTileView(file: file) // <- Another extracted view
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FileTileView: View {
    var file: File

    var body: some View {
        Text(file.name) // <- Doesn't get updated when CloudKit received the sync update
    }
}
```

**The code is the same, just couple of extracted views**. Why doesn't it work?